# Duda sobre declaración función Define

Tags: c

En una constante simbólica X definida por #define X 6-3. ¿Qué significa este rango?

Si tenemos una expresión, por ejemplo: 5 * X / 3. ¿Cuál seria la resolucion de X?

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X no es una constante. X es una macro.

---

La directiva `#define` es una orden del pre-procesador y está aislada completamente del proceso de compilación: ni el procesador se comunica con el compilador ni el compilador con el procesador.

Lo que hace la directiva `#define` es crear un símbolo de pre-procesador que será substituido antes de pasar el código al compilador, por lo tanto, éste código fuente:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define X 6-3

int main()
{
    printf("%d", 5 * X / 3);
    return 0;
}
```

No será el que vea el compilador, primero pasará el pre-procesador y dejará el código así:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{
    printf("%d", 5 * 6-3 / 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Que es igual que si hubiésemos hecho un buscar-reemplazar de `X` por `6-3`, y el resultado que se verá por pantalla será:

> ```
> 29
> ```

Que es el resultado de multiplicar `5 * 6` y restarle `3 / 3`.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me has ayudado mucho!